# VBA on MSWord: Is there an event for speak ended for SAPI.SpVoice object?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using VBA on Microsoft Word.
I've create the SAPI.SpVoice object:

```
Set speech = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
```

And I'm using it to read the selected paragraph:

```
Selection.Next(wdParagraph).Select
speech.Speak Selection.Text, 3
```

It works great. Now, when "speaking" is finished, I want the program to automatically move to the next paragraph and read it. i.e. to run the above two lines of code, again.

When I did something similar in C# I used the SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakCompleted event to invoke the "Move to the next paragraph and read it" function. I'm looking for the equivalent in VBA.

Any ideas?

Comment: When should it stop, when it reaches the end of the document? Should it look back around to the paragraphs above the selected one?

Comment: The above code moves to the next paragraph, marks it, and reads it. That's what I want the program to do. Mark a paragraph. Read it. Move to the next one. Mark it. Read it. Move to the next one...

Comment: And when should it stop?

Comment: I have a STOP button on a VBA form which stops the reading. When I'll have the event working, I'll have to add an additional flag telling the function not to invoke the "Read Next" function. Currently the "Stop" button runs:
    speech.Speak "", 3

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms722539%28v%3dvs.85%29 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723599%28v%3dvs.85%29 Why didn't you just read help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Apparently, the solution itself is simple but it didn't work since I had the wrong reference in VBA.

In VBA > Tools > Reference there were two appearances of "Microsoft Speech Object Library".

One was referencing to C:\Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore\common\sapi_onecore.dll
The other was referencing to C:\Windows\System32\Speech\Common\sapi.dll

The 2nd one is the right one.

After fixing this, I've just used the simple integrated event:

```
Private Sub speech_EndStream(ByVal StreamNumber As Long, ByVal StreamPosition As Variant)
    'Do stuff
End Sub
```